# How to define aliases with arguments?

Tags: shell

I can't retrieve the way to define a shell alias (in bash) like this one :

```
alias suppr='/usr/bin/find . -name "*~"  | xargs rm -f'
```

but with "**~" as a parameter of the alias.
I would like to use it like : suppr "*.bak" or suppr "*.svn" etc...

(it's just a dummy example here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function:

```
suppr() {
  /usr/bin/find . -name "$@" | xargs rm -f 
}
```

In general, functions are more flexible and safer to use than aliases.  In fact, many people argue that functions should always be used instead of aliases.

Comment: okay then, thx ! 
there's no other way to define it without a function ?

Comment: Aliases do not take arguments, and here is no reason to prefer an alias over a function.

Answer (score 2):

why not save your command as a script, and put the script in Path? you can name the script file as anything.